# Angular 2-8 way to display error without formbuilder by using material

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-forms, angular8

How to display validation error in my input, using Angular Material - Form Field, but without FormBuilder? 
I want to use it only with ngModel

https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

My Examplе:
That what I get and what I want to get with formBuilder

[image]

And It's what I got without

[image]

So my question - How to write logic from FormBuilder in my Html? 
Have we way to write something like this?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngClass="if !reqDateFrom: ErrorInput">
    <mat-label>From Date</mat-label>
    <input matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="reqDateFrom" value="{{fromDate}}">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template driven forms if you don't want to use reactive form, then you get the validation you wish. Also, don't use `value` if you are using `[(ngModel)]`, set the value to the model instead!

So if you go for a template driven form, remember to add also a `name` attribute, since that is how we register a form control under the hood. So try:

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>From Date</mat-label>
      <input matNativeControl name="reqDateFrom" [(ngModel)]="reqDateFrom" required>
    <mat-error>Required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9k5qp-avdytq?file=app/input-overview-example.html)**

Answer (score 0):

FormBuilder - formgroup give prebuilt validation with the angular material. 
If you are using ngModel you have to use ngClass to change to color red for error.
Please Check 
if the viewEncapsulation is set to none or you are using ng::deep in css o reflect the error in ngModel Validation